# Scraping data PRAW - How can I improve my code?

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, praw, coding-efficiency

**I have this code:**

```
posts = []

subs = list(set(['Futurology', 'wallstreetbets', 'DataIsBeautiful','RenewableEnergy', 'Bitcoin', 'Android', 'programming',
'gaming','tech', 'google','hardware', 'oculus', 'software', 'startups', 'linus', 'microsoft',  'AskTechnology', 'realtech', 
'homeautomation', 'HomeKit','singularity', 'technews','Entrepreneur', 'investing', 'BusinessHub', 'CareerSuccess', 
'growmybusiness','venturecapital', 'ladybusiness', 'productivity', 'NFT', 'CryptoCurrency']))

targeted_date = '01-09-19 12:00:00'
targeted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(targeted_date, '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')


for sub_name in subs:
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(sub_name).hot(limit = 1):
        date = submission.created
        date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)
        if date >= targeted_date and reddit.subreddit(sub_name).subscribers >= 35000:
            posts.append([date, submission.subreddit, reddit.subreddit(sub_name).subscribers, 
                      submission.title, submission.selftext])
        
df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns = ['date', 'subreddit','subscribers', 'title', 'text'])
df
```

Runtime with limit = 16 (~500 rows): **905.9099962711334 s**

**Which gives me this results:**

```
date    subreddit   subscribers title   text
0   2021-11-08 09:18:22 Bitcoin 3546142 Please upgrade your node to enable Taproot. 
1   2021-09-19 17:01:03 homeautomation  1333753 Looking for developers interested in helping t...   A while back I opened sourced all of my source...
2   2021-11-11 11:00:17 Entrepreneur    1036934 Thank you Thursday! - November 11, 2021 **Your opportunity to thank the** /r/Entrepren...
3   2021-11-08 01:36:05 oculus  396752  [Weekly] What VR games have you been enjoying ...   Welcome to the weekly recommendation thread! :...
4   2021-06-17 19:25:01 microsoft   141810  Microsoft: Official Support Thread  Microsoft: Official Support Thread\n\nMicrosof...
5   2021-11-12 11:02:14 investing   1946917 Daily General Discussion and spitballin thread...   Have a general question? Want to offer some c...
6   2021-11-12 04:16:13 tech    413040  Mars rover scrapes at rock to 'look at somethi...   
7   2021-11-12 12:00:15 wallstreetbets  11143628    Daily Discussion Thread for November 12, 2021   Your daily trading discussion thread. Please k...
8   2021-04-17 14:50:02 singularity 134940  Re: The Discord Link Expired, so here's a new ...   
9   2021-11-12 11:40:04 programming 3682438 It's probably time to stop recommending Clean ...   
10  2021-09-10 10:26:07 software    149655  What I do/install on every Windows PC - Softwa...   Hello, I have to spend a lot of time finding s...
11  2021-11-12 13:00:18 Android 2315799 Daily Superthread (Nov 12 2021) - Your daily t...   Note 1. Check [MoronicMondayAndroid](https://o...
12  2021-11-11 23:32:33 CryptoCurrency  3871810 Live Recording: Kevin O’Leary Talks About Cryp...   
13  2021-11-02 20:53:21 productivity    874076  Self-promotion/shout out thread This is the place to share your personal blogs...
14  2021-11-12 14:57:19 RenewableEnergy 97364   Northvolt produces first fully recycled batter...   
15  2021-11-12 08:00:16 gaming  30936297    Free Talk Friday!   Use this post to discuss life, post memes, or ...
16  2021-11-01 05:01:23 startups    884574  Share Your Startup - November 2021 - Upvote Th...   [r/startups](https://www.reddit.com/r/startups...
17  2021-11-01 09:00:11 HomeKit 107076  Monthly Buying Megathread - Ask which accessor...   Looking for lights, a thermostat, a plug, or a...
18  2021-11-01 13:00:13 dataisbeautiful 16467198    [Topic][Open] Open Discussion Thread — Anybody...   Anybody can post a question related to data vi...
19  2021-11-12 12:29:47 technews    339611  Peter Jackson sells visual effects firm for $1...   
20  2021-10-07 19:15:14 NFT 221897  Join our official —and the #1 NFT— Discord Ser...   
21  2020-12-01 12:11:36 google  1622449 Monthly Discussion and Support Thread - Decemb...   Have a question you need answered? A new Googl...
```

The issue is that it's taking way too much time. As you can see I set up a limit = 1 and it takes approx 1 min in to run. Yesterday, I set up the limit to 300, in order to analyze the data and it run for about 2 hours.

**My question:** Is there a way to change the code organization in order to limit the run time?

The bellow code used to work way faster, but I wanted to had a column subscriber number, and had to add a second for loop:

```
posts = []
subs = reddit.subreddit('Futurology+wallstreetbets+DataIsBeautiful+RenewableEnergy+Bitcoin+Android+programming+gaming+tech+google+hardware+oculus+software+startups+linus+microsoft+AskTechnology+realtech+homeautomation+HomeKit+singularity+technews+Entrepreneur+investing+BusinessHub+CareerSuccess+growmybusiness+venturecapital+ladybusiness+productivity+NFT+CryptoCurrency')
targeted_date = '01-09-19 12:00:00'
targeted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(targeted_date, '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')   

for subreddit in subs.new(limit = 500):
    date = subreddit.created
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)
    posts.append([date, subreddit.subreddit, subreddit.title, subreddit.selftext])

df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns = ['date', 'subreddit', 'title', 'text'])
df
```

Runtime with limit = 500 (500 rows): **7.630232095718384 s**

I know they aren't doing exactly the same thing but, the only reason why I tried to implement this new code is to add the new columns 'subscribers' which seems to work differently for the other calls.

Any suggestions/improvement to suggest?

Last one, anyone knows a way to retrieve all subreddit list based on a specific subject? (Such as technology) I found this page that list subreddits: https://www.reddit.com/r/ListOfSubreddits/wiki/listofsubreddits/#wiki_technology

Thanks :)

Comment: you can only get 1000 max posts with praw. Which part is taking too long? Did you try to find that?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Yes I read that the max was 1000, but for some reason I was able to create Dataframe with about 15000 raws of uniq data. Probably you can only retreive 1000 post per subreddit. I believe that the part that is taking long is the double iteration. It goes literally to each subreddit and retrieve 300 (if limit set = 300) rows

Comment: you can only get 1000 at a time, but if you just take the stream, you can keep on getting more and more.

Comment: The only thing I wish is to have the subscriber number. That why I had to rebuild the code, since it wasn't working with the faster one

Comment: If you have another way of getting the subscriber number, for example implemented with  the second code, it could work actually :)

Comment: `reddit.subreddit('pics').subscribers`

Comment: I tried this already with a different subreddit, it does work. But what I wanted to do is to access the number of subscribers from different subreddits, and implement it on my DF to the corresponding fields. It does work with my first code, unfortunately it's taking for ever to run, if I set up a limit upper 20...

Comment: looping over subreddit names, and getting their subscribers count takes forever? That doesn't seem right. You are probably doing something extra

Comment: All I do is taking the 'date', 'subreddit', 'subscribers', 'title' and 'text' * the limit set * the number of subreddits. Previously, I just had the 'date', 'subreddit', 'title' and 'text' and it wasn't taking much time. To add the 'subscribers' number to my DF, I had to change the first code I've made, which resolved in increasing the run time by a lot. I just wanted to check with the community, why the second version of my code was taking much more time, and if there were a way to improve it

Comment: It's possible that praw is requesting the count each time. Try to get it the first thing in the for loop, and then use the new saved variable.

Comment: Ok see, I thing your right, praw is probably requesting the subscriber number * the limit set, and do that for every subreddit (32). I will try what you suggested. Thanks @Mahrkeenerh :)

Comment: BTW just did some test: code Version 1 with limit = 500 (500 rows) runtime --> `7.630232095718384 s` | code Version 2 with limit = 16 (~500 rows) runtime --> `905.9099962711334 s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving your existing code by reducing converting and server calls (with explanations at the end):

```
posts = []

subs = list(set(['Futurology', 'wallstreetbets', 'DataIsBeautiful','RenewableEnergy', 'Bitcoin', 'Android', 'programming',
'gaming','tech', 'google','hardware', 'oculus', 'software', 'startups', 'linus', 'microsoft',  'AskTechnology', 'realtech', 
'homeautomation', 'HomeKit','singularity', 'technews','Entrepreneur', 'investing', 'BusinessHub', 'CareerSuccess', 
'growmybusiness','venturecapital', 'ladybusiness', 'productivity', 'NFT', 'CryptoCurrency']))

# convert target date into epoch format
targeted_date = '01-09-19 12:00:00'
targeted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(targeted_date, '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S').timestamp()


for sub_name in subs:
    subscriber_number = reddit.subreddit(sub_name).subscribers
    if subscriber_number < 35000: # if the subscribers are less than this skip gathering the posts as this would have resulted in false originally
        continue

    for submission in reddit.subreddit(sub_name).hot(limit = 1):
        date = submission.created # reddit uses epoch time timestamps
        if date >= targeted_date:
            posts.append([date, submission.subreddit, subscriber_number, 
                      submission.title, submission.selftext])

df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns = ['date', 'subreddit','subscribers', 'title', 'text'])
df
```

By separating your logic AND gate you are able to skip over those loops that would evaluate to false.

Instead of converting the date to a human-readable date inside of the for loop converting the target date once into the format that Reddit uses increases speed by removing the conversion operations and instead is just a look-up operation to compare numbers.

By storing the result of the number of subscribers you remove the number of calls to retrieve that information and instead are looking up the number in memory.